# Angular *ngFor propagates affected changes in one of the components to all of the remaining

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-components

Hello good people out there,
So I decided to create a custom component which I would then use in different parts of my Angular application.

Here is how my component looks like:

```
import {
    Role,
    MEMBER_ROLES
} from './role';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-role-chooser',
    template: 'app-role-chooer.component.html'
})
export class RoleChooserComponent, 
    implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    allRoles = MEMBER_ROLES;
    unSelectedRoles: Role[];
    selectedRoleId: string;

    // roles which has been assigned to this user
    @Input()
    selectedRoles: Role[];
    // user value from roles
    @Input()
    userId: string;
    // wheather we should commit changes to the server
    // or just return an update
    @Input()
    commitChanges = false;

    // notify other components when role has been removed
    @Output()
    onRemove = new EventEmitter<Role>();

    // notify other components when role has been added
    @Output()
    onAdd = new EventEmitter<Role>();

    // the flag to signal that "we're busy committing changes"
    committing = false;

    constructor() {}

    private _updateRoles() {
        // retain roles which have not been selected
        this.unSelectedRoles =
            this.allRoles.filter(role =>
                this.selectedRoles.indexOf(role) === -1);
        // console.log(this.unSelectedRoles);
    }

    private _fireUpdate(roleId: string, isAdded: boolean) {
        const roles = 
           (isAdded ? this.unSelectedRoles : this.selectedRoles);
        const index = roles
            .map(role => role.id)
            .indexOf(roleId);

        if (index !== -1) {
            const changed = roles[index];
            if (isAdded) {
                this.selectedRoles.unshift(changed);
                this.unSelectedRoles.splice(index, 1);
                this.onAdd.emit(changed);
            } else {
                this.selectedRoles.splice(index, 1);
                this.unSelectedRoles.unshift(changed);
                this.onRemove.emit(changed);
            }
        }
    }

    removeRole(roleId: string) {
        // check if we should commit changes
        if (this.commitChanges) {
            if (!this.userId) {
                throw new Error(
                  'commitChanges option requires ' + 
                  'that you also supply userId!');
            }
            // TODO: commit changes to the server.
            this.commiting = true;
        } else {
            // TODO: this code should real come 
            // after user role has been changed
            this._fireUpdate(roleId, false);
        }
    }

    acceptRole() {
        // console.log(this.selectedRoleId);
        if (this.commitChanges) {
            if (!this.userId) {
                throw new Error(
                    'commitChanges option requires ' + 
                    'that you also supply userId!');
            }
            // TODO: commit changes to the server.
            this.commiting = true;
        } else {
            // TODO: this code should real come
            // after user role has been changed
            this._fireUpdate(this.selectedRoleId, true);
        }
        // this.togglePopup();
    }

    ngOnInit() { this._updateRoles(); }
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.allRoles.length = 0;
        this.selectedRoles.length = 0;
        this.unSelectedRoles.length = 0;
        this.onAdd.unsubscribe();
        this.onRemove.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

And then, somewhere in my angular application, I'm trying to use it in yet another component, the snippet below is my usage.

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users">
    <td nz-td>
         <app-role-chooser
            (onRemove)="onRemoved()"
            (onAdd)="onAdded()"
            [userId]="user.id"
            [selectedRoles]="[]">
         </app-role-chooser>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

So, the component works fine, except for a fact that If I select or remove an Item, the entire list of items' components under the `NgFor` directive are also affected as if I did a batch update, which I didn't!

The screenshot below illustrate what I'm trying to solve.
[image]

Any one who can help. I would truly appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the answer. Just realized I was miss using the component. I used to bind `[selectedRoles]` attr (which is visible throughout the parent component) to a single value (Did angular create an implicit variable?). Instead, what I should've been done is using a different instance for each iteration in the `*ngFor`

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users">
<td nz-td>
     <app-role-chooser
        (onRemove)="onRemoved()"
        (onAdd)="onAdded()"
        [userId]="user.id"
        [selectedRoles]="selectedRolesByUserId[user.id]"> <---- this line was an evil
     </app-role-chooser>
</td>
```